# Get the Max value on an InputField in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input field that has a max and min value set.

'''

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100 mb-5" appearance="standard">
                    <mat-label style="font-size:23px;">Utility</mat-label>
                    <input matInput  style="font-size:23px;" type="number" id="Utility"
                           formControlName="Utility"
                           placeholder="Utility"
                           min="0"
                           max="1">
                    <mat-error style="font-size:15px;" *ngIf="showError('Utility', 'required')">Utility is required</mat-error>
                    <mat-error style="font-size:15px;" *ngIf="showError('Utility', 'min')">Minimum: 0</mat-error>
                    <mat-error style="font-size:15px;" *ngIf="showError('Utility', 'max')">Maximum: 1</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

'''

in .TS class

'''

```
Utility: new FormControl({ value: undefined }, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.min(0),
            Validators.max(1)
      ]),
```

'''

Wanted to know if there is a way to get the max value of \input Field(Utility) to check a condition?
In the below code, I want to get the max value of utility control and check against the user input.

'''

```
public showUtilityParameters = (controlName: string) => {
        return this.expectedEquipmentParametersForm.controls[controlName].value == "1";
    }
```

'''

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Validators are supposed to do that on their own - they'll return an error if input value is outside of min/max range.

Comment: when you add a Validators.min (or Validators.max) the "form.get('Utilty').errors" is an object. use `{{form.get('Utilty').errors|json}}` in the .html to see the properties of the object. SIm pretty sure the error has a property that is the min value